# Adding another answer to an old and accepted question

Tags: support, answers, old-questions

This is a question which was asked on 2012-11-18 and has an accepted answer:

[Set "Selected Item" in multiselect RadComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13444846/1427849)

I found another answer which may be correct as accepted answer. 
If I add my answer, what will happen? Will this question become active again?
Can I get some reputation from this answer if it is correct and gets up-votes?

Comment: Accept the answer which you found to be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, the answer will become active again if someone adds a new answer.
2. If you get upvotes, you'll certainly get rep from them.
3. The OP is [still active on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210982/rahul), so he might be inclined to change his accepted answer if yours is really good, and you'll get the +15 rep instead. I wouldn't count on that though after half a year.

Comment: Thanks Niels , I've added my answer :)

Comment: One thing I note @zey is that you haven't included any explanation. It's always worthwhile doing so as it helps explain the answer to the OP and future visitors. _Why_ does this answer the question?

Answer (score 4):

**Do not focus on the points.** Better focus to make good answers, write some text, together with source code, and well formatted. Do not just throw a link, or code.

If you have one more good answer - please add it, you may or may not get up-vote, probably fewer people see it from a brand new question of the same type/keywords

but you help anyone that search on the internet and come to that answer, and you also help if your answer is more updated than the old one.

From **my experience**, some day I was looking for something to solve, and found some answers to stackoverflow that did not solve it - then I discover a new library that helps me, and come back to SO and write about it, with out even a moment thinking the votes - and [look it now and still is not the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732488/how-can-i-convert-an-html-element-to-a-canvas-element/6789627#6789627), (and the one say "can not" the other say "you can"). I really do not care that is not the selected - from the votes is sure that helps some people.

So if you believe that you have something that can help, please write it.

Comment: Thanks Aristos , I've added my answer :)